# Trouble in displaying number of rows in table, Oracle express 11g DB

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I know two ways to display no. of rows one using count() - slower, other using user_tables -quickie.

> select table_name, num_rows from user_tables;

displays, null for 4 tables

```
TABLE_NAME  NUM_ROWS
TABLEP  
TABLEU  
TABLEN  
TABLE1  
TRANSLATE   26
```

but

```
select count(*) from tableu
```

gives,

```
COUNT(*)
6
```

What is the problem here, what should I do so that user_tables will be updated/ or whatever to show exact no. of rows. I have already tried issuing commit statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`num_rows` is not accurate since it depends on when is the last time [DBMS_STATS](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/cost-based-optimizer-and-database-statistics.php#dbms_stats) package was ran:

```
exec dbms_stats.gather_schema_stats('ONWER NAME');
```

Run stats like above and then re-run your query.

Answer (score 2):

You should not assume or expect that `num_rows` in `user_tables` is an accurate row count.  The only way to get an accurate row count would be to do a `count(*)` against the table.

`num_rows` is used by the cost-based optimizer (CBO) to provide estimates that drive query plans.  The actual value does not need to be particularly accurate for those estimates to generate query plans-- if the optimizer guesses incorrectly by a factor of 3 or 4 the number of rows that an operation will produce, that's still likely to be more than accurate enough.  This estimate is generated when statistics are gathered on the tables.  Generally, that happens late at night and only on tables that are either missing (`num_rows` is NULL) or are stale (generally meaning that roughly 20% of the rows are new or updated since the last time statistics were gathered).  And even then, the values that are generated are normally only estimates, they're not intended to be 100% accurate.

It is possible to call `dbms_stats.gather_table_stats` to force `num_rows` to be populated immediately before querying `num_rows` and to pass parameters to generate a completely accurate value.  Of course, that means that `gather_table_stats` is doing a `count(*)` under the covers (plus doing additional work to gather additional statistics) so it would be easier and more efficient to have done a `count(*)` directly in the first place.

Comment: thank you, stackoverflow doesn't allow me to accept both answers as correct. I got the num_rows query from here but no one said its estimate or depends on dbms_stats! I thought there is some internal trigger that does the job.